# bootstrap dropdown only on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown menu implemented with bootstrap3 where I wanna make the dropdown visible only on click instead of hover. My code at the moment:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" id="without-avatar" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
    <li>......</li>
    ......
  </ul>
</li>
```

I found some answers where it was said if I use `disabled` on the `a class` then the dropdown menu will be available only on click instead of hover. Unfortunately the code is not working. I guess the answer was outdated.

As of 2016 what is the preferred way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried running `$("#without-avatar").off("hover")`?

Comment: Tony, I haven't tried any js/jquery since I guess there should be a bootstrap way to solve this problem.

Comment: Looking at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns it has "none" in the options, so there doesn't appear to be any inherent support for disabling/enabling the hover.

Comment: Can you repro this in a jsfiddle?  I created one and it doesn't do anything on hover...

Comment: Does it do anything on click?

Comment: Yes, the click works.  I'm curious as generally dropdowns don't opn on hover...

Comment: I only could go this far: https://jsfiddle.net/ane4937e/. I haven't used jsfiddle before. Can you share yours?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tonyhinkle/Lmuun72f/11/.  You need to add jQuery to yours--click the gear icon in the script pane.  Do that and remove the "disabled" and then the dropdown works.

Comment: You don't even use the disabled version. Pretty weird. In my original code it's embedded into navbar. Maybe that causes the problem.

Comment: Tony, I solved the issue. It was my bad. I had some hover code embedded into the navbar part. Sorry for your time and thanks a lot for the help. If you write an answer that the basic behavior is the clickable version, then I will mark it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap dropdown does not drop down on hover.  Please check the code on the enclosing elements to find where the problematic hover event is defined.